# How to implement Gale-Shapely algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

For a personal project, I need to implement Gale-Shapely in python. Here's my implementation of that :

```
def gale_shapley(men_prefs, women_prefs):
free_men = list(men_prefs.keys())
relationships = {}
while free_men:
    print(free_men, relationships)
    man = free_men.pop(0)
    prefs = men_prefs[man]
    for woman in prefs:
        current_women_prefs = women_prefs[woman]
        spouse = relationships.get(woman)  # relationships[women] but none if none found
        if not spouse:
            # If woman isn't in a relationship, get her into one !
            relationships[woman] = man
            break

        elif current_women_prefs.index(spouse) > current_women_prefs.index(man):
            # if the man is prefered to the current spouse of the woman, we divorce and remarry
            relationships[woman] = man
            free_men.append(spouse)
            break

return relationships
```

This produces unstable marriages, and I cannot understand why. This is a simplified version, so the problem might come from somewhere else, but i'm not sure this algorithm is correct either. It sometimes produces good marriages, and sometimes not.

EDIT : Here's one of the cases where it fails.

```
print(gale_shapley({'A': ['4', '1', '3', '2'], 
                    'B': ['1', '3', '4', '2'],
                    'C': ['2', '1', '3', '4'],
                    'D': ['1', '3', '4', '2']},
                   {'1': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'C'],
                    '2': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B'],
                    '3': ['B', 'D', 'C', 'A'],
                    '4': ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}))

# {'4': 'A', '1': 'B', '2': 'C', '3': 'D'} is the result
# but D 3 would like to swap partners with B 1, so it's unstable
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `current_women_prefs.index(spouse) > current_women_prefs.index(man)` seems to be the wrong way around? And is it correct that if no woman is found, a free man is now popped from the `free_men` list and never returned?

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of input that produces bad output?

Comment: I disagree that the example output is unstable - D1/B3 would simply be another valid solution.  Note that both 1 and 3 prefer B to D, so somebody's going to have to settle for their second choice in any case.

Comment: @jasonharper Yeah, I just realized I had the bad definition. My answer shows the algorithm that utilizes the right definition. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had the bad definition of unstable marriage. I thought that, with the pairings (A,1), (B,2), if A liked 2 better than 1, and if 2 liked A better than B, then the marriages were unstable.

Actually, if A liked 2 better than 1, and if 2 liked A better than B, then the marriage is unstable.

The above code works to realize Gape-Shapely algorithm.

Here's my code for checking unstable marriages :

```
def paires_stables(men, women, men_prefs, women_prefs):
    for i in range(len(men)):
        current_pref = get_pref(men[i], women[i], men_prefs)
        for j in range(len(women)):
            if i != j and get_pref(men[i], women[j], men_prefs) < current_pref:
                if get_pref(women[j], men[i], women_prefs) < get_pref(women[j], men[j], women_prefs):
                    print("Instable :", men[i], women[j])
                    return False
    return True


def get_pref(actor, target, preferences):
    return preferences[actor].index(target)
```

Comment: Recommend you change "if not spouse" to "if spouse is None" to avoid an issue where if you're storing 0's then "not spouse" will return a True for those 0 values.